# How to model a stochastic process, continuous in stepsize, which converges against a simple random walk?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, random-walk

I want to compute the probability distribution for a stochastic process with discrete number of steps, where each real value has a nonvanishing probability to be the next stepsize. And I want to introduce a parameter $t$ such that I end up with a simple finite stepsize random walk in the limit of small/big $t$.

For a random walk with steps $+1$ and $-1$ with probabilities $p_+$ and $p_-=1-p_+$, the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) is
$$\phi(a)=\sum_{k=1}^2p_k \mathrm e^{ikx}$$
and when I add up $n$ steps, I end up with 
$$(p_-\mathrm e^{ix}+p_+\mathrm e^{-ix})^n$$ 
which must be fourier transformed. I draw my information from this [book on Kinetic theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387955518), but that one is about physics, really.I also find these terms on the Wikipedia page [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with somewhat different notation.

Now my attempt for the continuous approach is to replace "$+1$ and $-1$ with probabilities $p_+$ and $p_-=1-p_+$" by the continuous distribution with two peaks, i.e. if $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is the stepsite, the probability should be, I think

$$a_+(t)\ \mathrm e^{-(\lambda-1)^2/2t}+a_-(t)\ \mathrm e^{-(\lambda+1)^2/2t}$$

with the right normalizations $a_\pm(t)$. But how to compute that to the power of the stepsize $(\dots)^n$ to obtain the probability?

If the integral is too difficult, can we approximately solve it? Or is there a more reasonable approach? For starters, $p_+=p_-=\tfrac{1}{2}$ is of interest. One could of course also make variable peaks, which at the moment are set to $+1$ / $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to revolve around the idea of *mollifying* the $\pm1$ steps of a discrete random walk by some gaussian distributions of smaller and smaller width.

In terms of random variables, one replaces each $\pm1$ step $X$ such that $P[X=+1]=p$ and $P[X=-1]=q$ with $q=1-p$, by a step $X^t$ defined by
$$
X^t=X+Z^t,
$$ 
where $Z^t$ is normal $N(0,t)$. The density $f^t$ of the distribution of $X^t$ is such that
$$
f^t(x)=\frac{p\mathrm e^{-(x-1)^2/2t}+q\mathrm e^{-(x+1)^2/2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}.
$$
Likewise, the sum of $n\geqslant1$ i.i.d. steps distributed like $X^t$ is 
$$
S^t_n=S_n+Z^t_n,
$$ 
where $S_n$ is the sum of the $\pm1$ steps $X$, hence $\frac12(S_n+n)$ is binomial $(n,p)$, and $Z^t_n$ is the sum of the normal steps $Z^t$ hence $Z^t_n$ is normal $N(0,nt)$. The density $f_n^t$ of the distribution of $S^t_n$ is the convolution of $f^t$ with itself $n$ times, that is, $f_n^t$ is such that
$$
f_n(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi nt}}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}p^kq^{n-k}\mathrm e^{-(x-2k+n)^2/2nt}.
$$
To realize every random variable $S_n^t$ on a common probability space (hence being able to consider almost sure limits), simply consider
$$
S^t_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k+\sqrt{t}\sum_{k=1}^nY_k,
$$
where the sequence $(X_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. $\pm1$ Bernoulli, the sequence $(Y_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. standard normal and the two sequences are independent.